# Invalid syntax for Python MIMETEXT

Tags: python, email

I followed a tutorial in youtube for sending email in python using outlook, however I have received an error when running the python file.

This is my python script :

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

sender_email_address = 'nmahirahaqilah.awahab@gmail.com'
sender_email_password = 'mypassword'
receiver_email_address = 'mahirah.abd.wahab@ericsson.com'

email_subject_line = 'Sample python email'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender_email_address
msg['To'] = receiver_email_address
msg['Subject'] = email_subject_line

email_body = 'Hello World'
msg.attach(MIMEText(email_body,'plain'))

email_content = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.outlook.com:587')

serverstarttls()
server.login(sender_email_address,sender_email_password)

server.sendmail(sender_email_address,receiver_email_address,email_content)
server.quit()
```

This is the error that I am receiving, not quite sure why:

```
C:\Users\Azril\Desktop>python email.py
  File "email.py", line 3
    from email.mime.text
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: That looks fine. Perhaps you have some invisible characters in there. Try retyping that section from scratch.

Comment: Also, don't call your file `email.py`.

Comment: Hi guys, I've changed the filename to test.py ,however i still got the same error.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help, i got it , but i got this error somehow                   
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREA
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed                                                         any idea why?